# MongoDB Javascript Batch Insert Unique Constraint

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm a little confused about the MongoDB native JS driver and inserts given unique constraints.  Reading here, http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html, it appears that after an insert, a "success" callback can be passed that can handle the saved documents (perhaps grabbing the _id field from the saved documents, for instance).

But, suppose I'm saving user profiles, each which have an email field. I want the email fields to be unique, so I figure I must use ensureIndex. Then suppose I want to batch insert 10 user profiles, each with an email field, but 2 of those 10 emails already exist in my database. Well by the unique constraint, those 2 user profiles won't get added to the database, right? Then what comes back in the callback? 8 saved documents? or 8 saved documents AND 2 pre-existing documents?

EDIT:
After a little testing I've made some good progress, but I'm still missing one piece. I'll explain continuing my example from above. Suppose I have a collection of user profiles with 1 document in it, and that document has a field with "email": "ex@mple.com". Then suppose I put an index with { unique: true } on the email field in this collection. If I then perform a simple insert:

```
collection.insert({ 'email': 'ex@mple.com' }, { safe: true }, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);                                                         
});
```

results in the callback above comes back undefined, because a document with that email already existed, so no insert was performed. That makes plenty of sense, but what I would like is for "results" to come back containing the document that already existed, that prevented the new insertion. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : 1, email : "email" }
> db.collection.ensureIndex({email: 1}, {unique: true})
> db.collection.insert({_id:2, email: "email"})
E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.collection.$email_1  dup key: { : "email" }
```

Can you parse the duplicate key error message, "E11000 duplicate key..." to get "email" and subsequently issue a find() to get the pre-existing doc that prevented insertion?

Since there will only be one document- db.collection.find(email: "email")